# WordPress search results multiple loops

Tags: wordpress, search

The following is my search.php:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <h2 class="pagetitle">Page Search Results</h2>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if ($post->post_type == 'page') : ?>
             Show Page results
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php rewind_posts(); ?>
    <h2 class="pagetitle">Post Search Results</h2>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if ($post->post_type != 'page') : ?>
             Show non-page results
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
 No Results
<?php endif; ?>
```

The code allows search results under posts to be separated from those found in pages. If no search results are found for either posts or pages, the text "No Results" is displayed.

However, when results are found for pages but NOT posts (and vice versa), under the 'Post Search Results" there is nothing displayed. I would like the code tweaked so that if there are no results found under "Post Search Results" but there are results found under "Page Search Results," the text "No Results" is displayed underneath the "Post Search Results" header.

Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, you can expand the array to include any post_type your site is using:

```
<?php
    foreach (array('post','page') as $pt) :
        $search_query = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type'         => $pt,
                's'                 => $s,
                'posts_per_page'    => 10,
                'paged'             => $paged
            )
        );
    ?>
    <?php if ($pt == 'post') : ?>
        <h2 class="pagetitle">Post Search Results</h2>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h2 class="pagetitle">Page Search Results</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php 
        if ($search_query->have_posts()) : while ($search_query->have_posts()) : $search_query->the_post();
        if ($pt == 'post') :
    ?>
        Post Results Code
    <?php else : ?>
        Page Results Code
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; else : ?>
        No Results
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I have different formatting for the results depending on whether they are found in posts or pages. Does the code take that into consideration? Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: Ok, the code is returning results for posts but not pages. After doing several searches for obvious words contained in a few pages, I'm still getting "No Results". Also, I need two separate title headers for the results similar to my original code. Thanks Cookie

Comment: Sorry, had an extra "s" in the foreach array.

Comment: It now pulls results from both pages and posts. The problem now is that if results are found in pages but not posts, the "Page Search Results" header is displayed but not the "Post Search Results." I need both headers to display always even if there are "No Results" for one. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Also, the above code does not account for if no results are found under BOTH pages and posts. I would need an additional unique message to display in such circumstances. Really, thanks again.

Comment: It'd be the same if/else statement that is used for the different loop and different headers.

Comment: To be clear, in this case, the "Page Search Results" and "Post Search Results" headers should not be displayed if no results are found under either. I would have a separate message entirely.

Comment: I've inserted the additional if/else statement I'd like to be displayed that would replace entirely the "Page Search Results"/"No Results" and "Post Search Results"/"No Results" but am getting fatal errors. Any idea what to do?

Comment: I'd say undo, stick with the code before you added the if/else statements. I know it won't completely do what you were hoping, but that would take a bit more work.